# How to bind Listbox (select size="n") item values to IEnumerable<int>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ienumerable, html-select, model-binding

I have a select element on my form. I fill its contents with javascript. The view model has a property called Fruits of type IEnumerable. Is it possible to bind this select to that property when I submit the form? So to make it clear, assume there's a form with a select of size 5, which at the same time is empty. Then I add some items (options) to that select with java script:

```
 <select size="5">
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="2">Banana</option>
  <option value="3">Grape</option>
  <option value="4">Pinapple</option>
 </select>
```

When I submit the form, I want the Fruits property to contain the above option values. How's that done? I can't think of any way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it, something's missing though. To overcome the first problem of getting an empty ListBox on the view I did this:

```
 ListBoxFor(x=>x.Fruits,new List<SelectListItem>(),new{style="width:160px;display:block"})
```

This will bring up an empty `<select multiple="multiple" size="5" name="Fruits">` to the view. Then I add some items to the listbox with javascript (to be precise, add options to the select). The biggest pain started after this. When submitting the form the Fruits property was null, so listbox items were not getting bound. After lots of digging I discovered that in order for a ListBox items to bind to some collection the desired ones need to be selected. So even if there're 10 items in the listbox, they won't get bound to my Fruits model property unless I select them before submitting. After selecting the added items the Fruits property contained the corresponding values. However I hate to have to select all the items after adding them. I know this can be done automatically with javascript, but it'd be good to bypass this by some other means.